# ¿Por que no me funciona el update en php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Mi problemática es la siguiente, hice algo simple, un botón modificar en un modal que me muestra los datos triados desde una tabla, la idea es que al presionar  el botón modificar se me guarden los cambios realizados en el formulario que me mostraba los datos de la tabla y mostrar esos cambios en la tabla pero al usar ajax y php esto no me funciona

Me lanza un mensaje de que el procedimiento se llevo a cabo con éxito pero los cambios no se realizan en la base de datos, ya revise los nombres de las variables, sintaxys y todo lo que podría haber hecho fallar pero no se que pasa, me envía bien los datos pero no ejecuta la consulta update, es como si pasara de largo, alguien que sepa a que se deba?

Aquí el código PHP:

```
 <?php 
    include "conexion.php";



    $id=(isset($_POST['eid']))?$_POST['eid']:"";
    $rut=(isset($_POST['rut']))?$_POST['rut']:"";
    $nombre=(isset($_POST['nombre']))?$_POST['nombre']:"";
    $telefono=(isset($_POST['telefono']))?$_POST['telefono']:"";
    $direccion=(isset($_POST['direccion']))?$_POST['direccion']:"";
    $comuna=(isset($_POST['comuna']))?$_POST['comuna']:"";
    $genero=(isset($_POST['genero']))?$_POST['sexo']:"";
    $tipo=(isset($_POST['tipo_Licencia']))?$_POST['tipo_licencia']:"";


                        $sql = "UPDATE archivo_pdf SET rut='$rut',

                                                        nombre='$nombre',

                                                        telefono='$telefono',

                                                        direccion='$direccion',

                                                        comuna='$comuna',

                                                        sexo='$genero',

                                                        tipo_licencia='$tipo'

                                        where id_archivo='$id'";


    echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) ;



 ?>
```

y aqui el AJAX:

```
    $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"control/ActualizarDatos.php",
    data:cadena,
    success:function(r){

      if(r==1){

       $('#tabla').load('control/tabla.php');
        alertify.success("Actualizado con exito");

      }else{

        alertify.error("Fallo el servidor ");

      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: y cual es el error que te da?

Comment: ninguno, ese es el problema, solo no me modifica los datos pero me dice que la consulta se llevo a cabo sin ningún problema y no entiendo por que, si se llevara a cabo me guardaría los cambios entonces...en eso quedo estancado

Comment: verificaste tus variables? es decir que el tipo de variables corresponda; por ejemplo `telefono='$telefono'` `$telefono` sea de tipo `int` o `string`? porque a mi me pasa a veces al revés, suelo poner las variables sin `''` en variables de tipo `string` y obviamente la consulta no lo hace
prueba revisando tus variables
si son string `'$string'` usa las comillas y si son int `$int` quita las comillas, lo de tipo de variables me refiero en tu base de datos, int, varchar etc
por ejemplo `'$id'` lo estas pasando como string en la consulta, y si el id en tu base de datos es int, es como si escribie

Comment: deberias de chequear es el id, probablemente esta en null

Comment: y $result que tiene? esta ejecutando la consulta? devuelve algo alli?

Comment: Bienvenido Briuk, te invito a hacer el [tour] podras ganar unas medallas y conocer como funcionamos

Comment: Las sentencias update se llevan a cabo exitosamente independientemente hayan modificado o no un registro en específico. Claro, siempre que estén correctamente escritas. Considero que en este caso el id viene vacío y por lo tanto se ejecuta correctamente, tienes un condicional ternario en donde si viene vacío, coloca "" nada en el id. Verifica si realmente viene el id que quieres afectar.

Comment: creo que tienes razón Edgard, acabo de revisar y los datos que no se envían bien son la id y el genero en el archivo php, veré como resolver eso y cuando lo logre les aviso, gracias por comentar :D

Comment: Valida que el id sea obligatorio.

Comment: Revisa los datos de acceso a la base de datos. Podrías tener un error en la variable $conexion. Muestra el código de conexion.php para ver eso. Y verifica nombre de BD, UserBD y password. También hay que revisar los nombres del formulario que aporta los datos tipo Post. Algún nombre podría estar mal escrito

Comment: acabo de verificar en ambas partes, ajax, html y php, tanto ajax como php me capturan bien los datos porque los mostre a traves de mensajes, el problema es la id, por alguna razon no me la toma en la consulta a pesar de estar bien escrita y que si se guarda en la variable como ya vi mostrandola a traves de mensaje, pero a pesar de eso la consulta no genera cambios porque no encuentra la id(?) no se que pasa, itente guardar en la variable la id de forma directa osea el mismo numero que se guarda cuando lo pido desde el formulario y solo de esa forma me funciona, no se si me explico bien...

Comment: esa variable ya la revise, la cosa es que la consulta y todo se ejecuta bien el problema es que al guardar el dato en la variable $id no me toma la consulta, osea los datos se envian, se guardan en todas las variables incluyendo la $id, pero no se por cual razon simplemente no la ejecuta bien, es como si se ejecutara de forma invisible porque si me manda el resultado de que se ha ejecutado, no se si me explico pero no entiendo por que pasa

Comment: Bueno acabo de resolverlo y primero que nada me disculpo porque era un error super minimo que pase por alto ya que como mencione antes, estaba verificando si me enviaba los datos a las variables y eso llevo a mi confusión, pero para aclarar dudas y si sirve de ayuda para alguna persona dejare constancia de eso el error no estaba finalmente en el codigo PHP sino que en el Ajax, en la cadena tenia escrito "id_archivo" que pase por alto el modificarlo ya que primeramente antes de comenzar a modificar variables y tal para lograr detectar el error, ese nombre de la cadena lo deje tal cual como lo t